# What's the difference between public interfaces and published interfaces in Java?

Tags: java, interface

I've read these two pages

- http://martinfowler.com/ieeeSoftware/published.pdf
- http://lambda-the-ultimate.org/node/1400

but I still don't get the difference between a published and public method.  An example in Java would be helpful.  Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please reference those pages so we know what context you are referring to.

Comment: What is a published interface? I have never heard that term before.

Comment: In general (not referring to any particular language implementation), a "published" interface is one that the general programming community is expected and allowed to use.  A "public" interface, on the other hand, is merely one that is accessible without having to "jailbreak" the device or use reflections or some such.  This is a bit muddled with Java since the two almost correspond 1:1.

Comment: http://martinfowler.com/ieeeSoftware/published.pdf
http://lambda-the-ultimate.org/node/1400

I've read these two pages

Comment: what is published interface???

Comment: @Rugal - read the comment two above yours.

Comment: @tbodt Well, you can be completely clueless and still write an on-topic question. I'd say the issue is more about not knowing how to write the question to everyone's standards (and I'd say give 'em at least a little bit of leeway as long as they're willing to fix it)

Comment: **What is a published interface?* Given the meaning of the word 'publish,' a published interface is a public interface released outside of the developing organization for use by outside clients.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**public**

Public interfaces written in Java:

```
    interface MyInterface { ... }

    public interface MyInterface { ... }

    class MyClass() {
        void anotherInterface() { ... }
        public void someOtherInterface() { ... }
    }
```

All of them are public because they are not only available for internal objects.

**published**

The status of *published interface* is not part of the Java language, it is part of what some may call application architecture. It is in a higher level of abstraction.

Now, the relationship between the two:

- Every published interface is a public interface.
- Not every public interface is a published interface.

**Note:** The concept does not apply literally to only Java interfaces, it could also be class, methods etc.

To dig deeper: [Public versus Published
Interfaces](http://martinfowler.com/ieeeSoftware/published.pdf)

Comment: correct! published interface is just a name of higher layer call. some usage or name in web service or some sort!

Comment: Why are you using `class` for `interfaces`?

Comment: @PM Interface is just the methods or fields that can be accessed. You shouldn't take it too literally mean `interface`.

Comment: @PM77-1 I have updated the answer, thanks. However, the concept does not apply literally to only Java interfaces.

Comment: You are misinterpreting the term "interface".  "Interface" has a generic meaning, outside the meaning of the Java `interface` keyword.

Comment: For example, `Charge.create()` is both public, and part of the published stripe API, while [`ChargeRefundCollectionDeserializer.deserialize()`](https://github.com/stripe/stripe-java/blob/master/src/main/java/com/stripe/model/ChargeRefundCollectionDeserializer.java#L17) is public, but not published.  Developers using the Stripe library in their projects should not be using the deserializer directly, so Stripe should be able to change the signature of deserialize without breaking programs using the library.